# Does centripetal or centrifugual acceleration simulate gravity?

Tags: forces

[image: masterpiece of a skilled artist]

Assume mass, radius and tangential velocity as constant at every curved part. If this system could simulate the effects of gravity, what force would be responsible for doing so? If not, how do I alter it to simulate the effects of gravity?
P.S. if I placed a human on the **inner side** of the curved part and rotated them, will they feel weight?

Comment: Yes it would, the centrifugal force (which "appears" in the rotating frame) would feel like gravity if the rotating device is large enough (so that the force field is parallel).

Comment: That depends on how you define the "effects of gravity". If you just want the daily effects like "weight", yes you will get that in a rotating frame of reference. However for example the earth distorts spacetime in a way, that you cannot simulate in flat spacetime by choosing a frame of reference.

Comment: The 'effect' I desire is only weight.

Comment: And please answer the edited question. I asked for the forces acting on a human placed on the inner part of the curved surface.

Comment: Centrifugal forces, y'all say?

Comment: Sure, have you seen [Gravitron](https://youtu.be/G1wcwCaqDMg), amusement park device ? It generates outwards force which pushes participants to the walls. Same concept can be used to construct "artificial gravity" in huge orbital/outer-space cosmic stations,  for example station with $150~\text{km}$ in radius will just need to rotate once per $2~\text{minutes}$ to generate artificial "gravity" of $1g$. Btw same centrifugal force is used to dry your clothes in washing machine.